# Bound mismatch error and java generic method

Tags: java, generics, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the following error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method constructPage(WebDriver, int, Class<T>) of type     
Page<T> is not applicable for the arguments (WebDriver, int, Class<HomePage>). The 
inferred type HomePage is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends 
Page<T>>
```

I am trying to do a login and return a HomePage, if successful and a LoginPage if not using generics.

I have a base class, Page which is extended by SecuredPage for pages behind the login wall. I wrote a generic helper method that would construct pages of any type. This method is used by the login method on the LoginPage. LoginPage extends Page and HomePage extends SecuredPage. SecuredPage extends Page. The login method works if the LoginPage is returned, but I get the above error trying to return a HomePage. Since HomePage is a subclass of page because its parent class extends Page, I am confused as to why HomePage is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Page<T>>`.

```
public abstract class Page<T extends Page<T>> extends SlowLoadableComponent<T> {

    protected static final <T extends Page<T>> T constructPage(WebDriver driver, 
    int timeoutInSeconds, java.lang.Class<T> pageClass) 
    {
        Page<T> p = null;

        try {
            Constructor<T> pageConstructor = pageClass.getConstructor(
            WebDriver.class, String.class, Integer.TYPE);
            p = pageConstructor.newInstance(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl(), 
                timeoutInSeconds);
            p.get();

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }

        return pageClass.cast(p);       
    }
}
```

This is the SecuredPage class:

```
public class SecuredPage extends Page<SecuredPage> {

    .....
}
```

And this is HomePage:

```
public final class HomePage extends SecuredPage {
    ......
}
```

This is LoginPage:

```
public final class LoginPage extends Page<LoginPage>  {


    public final HomePage loginWithGoodCredentials(final User user) {
        return login(user, HomePage.class);
    }

    public final LoginPage loginWithBadCredentials(final User user) {
        return login(user, LoginPage.class);
    }


    public final <T extends Page<T>> T login(final User user, final Class<T>     
            expectedPage) {
        enterUsername(user.getUsername());
        enterPassword(user.getPassword());
         loginButton.click();

        return Page.constructPage(getDriver(), getTimeoutInSeconds(), 
        expectedPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: a bound `class Page<T extends Page<T>>` is almost NEVER useful in Java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `HomePage` is a `Page<SecuredPage>` and not a `Page<HomePage>`.  The `login` method would return a `Page<HomePage>` from its generic signature.

You must make the generic parameter of `HomePage` related to itself, not `SecuredPage`.  This will resolve the compiler error.  Keep `SecuredPage` generic, but make sure its bound extends `SecuredPage<T>`.  Then assign `HomePage` itself for the generic parameter `T` in `HomePage`.

```
class SecuredPage<T extends SecuredPage<T>> extends Page<T> {
...
}
class HomePage extends SecuredPage<HomePage>  {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `login(user, SecuredPage.class)` works, but `login(user, HomePage.class)` does not. The reason is: type parameter `T` in `SecuredPage` is `SecuredPage`. `HomePage` is a subclass of `SecuredPage`, so the `T` type parameter of `HomePage` is `SecuredPage` as well.

Now, you call `login` with a `Page<HomePage>`. But such a class does not exist. `HomePage` is a subclass of `Page<SecuredPage>`.

Comment: So,what do I need to do in the class declaration for SecuredPage in order for this to work? I am not super experienced with generics, obviously....

Comment: Would something like this be right: public class SecuredPage<T extends SecuredPage<T>> extends Page<T> and then HomePage could be: public class HomePage extends SecuredPage<HomePage>?

Comment: All superclasses must have the generic parameter `T`, only the concrete subclasses classes can have the self-recurring type. I'd implement an `AbstractSecuredPage<T>` and a final class `SecuredPage`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I accepted the answer from rgettman because it solved my problem and I can't make SecuredPage a final class. I need to be able to extend it. Unfortunately, I can't vote up _your_ answer because I don't have enough reputation, which is too bad because you pinpointed the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you still wish `HomePage` to extend `SecuredPage` with the presence of ***Bounded Generics***, please pass the '*Generic Substitution*' till HomePage.

Do not substitute ***Generic*** at `SecuredPage`, instead make `SecuredPage` as

```
public class  SecuredPage<T extends Page<T>> extends Page<T> {

}
```

and while creating `HomePage`, declare the value for the generic like this,

```
public class HomePage extends SecuredPage<HomePage> {

}
```

This should essentially solve the error

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of your `constructPage` method, you could just use

```
protected static final <T extends Page<?>> T constructPage(...) 
{
    Page<?> p = null;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wish I could accept two answers because your answer highlights something about generics that took me forever to get.

Answer (score 0):

If you any one still face the same error change JDK 1.8 or latest version in compiler level from 
Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > "Compiler Compilation level" -> 1.8