# Type mismatch error in method with generic return (Why do I have to do a cast to the generic type in this method, but not in similar ones?)

Tags: java, generics, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I am getting the following error from a method in which I need a generic return type:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from PageTypeOne to P SecuredPage.java
```

I can get rid of the error by casting the object to the generic type parameter, but I don't understand why I am required to do this in this particular method, but not in other similar methods I have written elsewhere in other classes.

The basic structure of the project is this:

A base class Page for unsecured web pages
A base class SecuredPage for all secured web pages

I had a similar question earlier today which was solved with help from the Stack Overflow community: [Bound mismatch error and java generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883896/bound-mismatch-error-and-java-generic-method).

I am now having another problem with a similar method.

The base page class w/ helper method that builds pages is this:

```
public abstract class Page<T extends Page<T>> extends SlowLoadableComponent<T> {

    protected static final <T extends Page<T>> T constructPage(WebDriver driver, 
    int timeoutInSeconds, java.lang.Class<T> pageClass) 
    {
        Page<T> p = null;

        try {
            Constructor<T> pageConstructor = pageClass.getConstructor(
                WebDriver.class, String.class, Integer.TYPE);
            p = pageConstructor.newInstance(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl(), 
                timeoutInSeconds);
            p.get();

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }

        return pageClass.cast(p);       
    }
}
```

SecuredPage class is as follows:

```
public class SecuredPage<T extends SecuredPage<T>> extends Page<T> {

    .....
}
```

This is the method I am trying to implement from within SecuredPage -- I want to be able to have a single method which will return both types of pages that result from opening a link in a method in my web application:

```
public final <P extends SecuredPage<P>> P loadContext(final String context) throws
NoSuchElementException {
    Menu m = pageHeader.getMenu();
    WebElement link = m.clickLink(context);
    String linkHref = link.getAttribute("href");

    if (linkHref.contains("somematchtext")) {
            return Page.constructPage(getDriver(), getTimeoutInSeconds(),   
                PageTypeOne.class); <==== This is where I get the error
    } else if (linkHref.contains("someothermatchtext")) {
            return Page.constructPage(getDriver(), getTimeoutInSeconds(), 
                PageTypeTwo.class); <==== This is wheere I get the error
    }
 }
```

PageTypeOne and PageTypeTwo both extend SecuredPage:

```
public final class PageTypeOne extends SecuredPage<PageTypeOne> {
    .....
}


public final class PageTypeTwo extends SecuredPage<PageTypeTwo> {
    .....
}
```

I have a similar method in my LoginPage class which returns a LoginPage if someone attempts to log in with invalid credentials, and a HomePage (which extends SecuredPage), if they log in with valid credentials. I don't get this error with that method. Nor do I get the error with the constructPage method in my Page class, so I don't really understand why I am getting this error with my loadContext method in SecuredPage:

```
public final class LoginPage extends Page<LoginPage>  {

    public final HomePage loginWithGoodCredentials(final User user) {
        return login(user, HomePage.class);
    }

    public final LoginPage loginWithBadCredentials(final User user) {
        return login(user, LoginPage.class);
    }

    public final <T extends Page<T>> T login(final User user, final Class<T>     
        expectedPage) {
        enterUsername(user.getUsername());
        enterPassword(user.getPassword());
        loginButton.click();

        return Page.constructPage(getDriver(), getTimeoutInSeconds(), 
            expectedPage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the compiler infer a method generic type (`P` in your case) from the method signature (`loadContext` in your case).  But `loadContext` method doesn't use `P` on the parameters to help the compiler infer `P`.

Instead you are forcing the compiler to infer the type `P` from within the method. You want to make it believe is `PageTypeOne`. Is not working like this.

Imagine that someone specified the generic parameter on the method call:

```
securedpageInstance.<SomeCompliantClassWithPBounds>loadContext(...)
```

`SomeCompliantClassWithPBounds` might be different from `PageTypeOne`.

Your second example works because you have `Class<T>` on `login` method signature. The compiler knows who is `T` and is sure that the return type is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with dcernahoschi's answer.

To go on, you may define `loadContext` as `public final SecuredPage<? extends SecuredPage<?>> loadContext(...)` and work with an "unknown" subclass of `SecuredPage` from here on out.
You could also change the code in `loadContext` to `return (P) Page.constructPage(...);` and later on, "trick" the compiler into allowing something like `PageTypeOne page = loadContext(...);`

I would highly suggest using the first approach, as the calling code should not know the outcome of `loadContext()`. If on the other hand, the calling code expects a certain page to be loaded, it should pass along the class of the page (and you get rid of the `if/else` in `loadContext`), as your login example does.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go with the wildcard option. That works beautifully for my purposes and I don't have any compiler warnings.